# MySQL: добавление данных в таблицу

Tags: mysql, запрос

Только начинаю программировать на php. Во время исполнения данного запроса подключение к базе проходит нормально и доступ тоже дается, но данные в таблицу не добавляются. Подскажите, что я делаю не так - почему так происходит?

```
<?php
$Pole2   = $POST["urname"]; 
$Pole1   = $POST["kod_point"]; 
$Pole3   = $POST["date"]; 
$Pole4   = $POST["product"]; 
$Pole5   = $POST["tarif"]; 
$Pole6   = $POST["adname"]; 
$Pole7   = $POST["telephone"]; 
$Pole8   = $POST["adress"];  


$dsn = 'mysql.hostinger.ru';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'XXX';
$mysqli = new mysqli($dsn, $user, $password);



$link = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.ru","root","XXX","db") or die("Невозможно подключиться к базе " . mysqli_error($link)); 
$db="db";
$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_select_db ($link,db) or die ("Невозможно открыть $db");
 $query = "INSERT INTO REQUESTED (КОД ТОРГОВОЙ ТОЧКИ, ИМЯ ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО ЛИЦА, ДАТА ПОДАЧИ ЗАЯВКИ, ПРОДУКТ(ЛИНЕЙНОЕ ИЛИ ИНТЕРАКТИВНОЕ ТВ), ТАРИФ, Ф.И.О, ТЕЛЕФОН, АДРЕС) VALUES ('$Pole1.', '$Pole2', '$Pole3', '$Pole4', '$Pole5', '$Pole6', '$Pole7', '$Pole8')";

if($query) echo "not NULL\n"; else "query is NULL\n";
$result = mysqli_query ($link,  $query);
if ($result) echo "Добавлено в базу данных.";
 else echo "Don't added to $db";
mysqli_close ( $link);
?>
```

Comment: 1) никогда не пользуйтесь неанглийскими буквами (в том числе пробелами) для таблиц/полей 2) что такое `$POST`? Может `$_POST`? 3) Что будет, если в `$_POST['adress']` я передам "1');DROP TABLE REQUESTED;"? (будет плохо) 4) Чтобы самому ловить ошибки запросов, достаточно вывести сгенерированный запрос и выполнить его ручками в консоли `mysql`. Тогда вопрос будет не по коду, а по запросу

Comment: До запроса записи данных выполнение этого кода не дойдет. Если там конечно не описка :) в строке mysqli_select_db ($link,db) ...

Comment: @Visman, судя по выводимым сообщениям-маркерам запросы '$link = mysqli_connect' и 'mysqli_select_db ($link,db)' происходят нормально. Т.к. последнее выводимое сообщение после выполнения  'not NULL  Don't added to db'.

Comment: @Visman, в данном случае, скорее всего это отработает нормально. Если php видит непонятную константу, то он пишет варнинг и считает, что значение константы равно ее имени, а в данном случае `$db` равно `db`, если сменить имя базы (и на сервере не будет базы db), то тогда будет ошибка

Comment: @BOPOH, спасибо - ваш совет очень помог. Теперь запрос проходит нормально. Единственный минус - если поля заполнены русскими символами, то они заносятся пустыми. С цифрами и латиницей работает совершенно нормально

Answer (score 1):

В запросе на вставку у вас имена полей включают пробелы. Пробелы и ключевые слова нужно экранировать при помоши обратного апострафа(`` ` ``).

Так-же вы некоректно получаете POST-параметры - PHP кладет их в глобальную переменную `$_POST`.

Крайне нежелательно вставлять параметры в запрос напрямую, как делеаете это вы - в текушем варианте код крайне не безопасен т.к. все парамеры уязвимы для SQL-иньекций. Научитесь использовать prepared statements.

Выполнять запросы под `root` тоже не особо хорошо - этот пользователь предназначен только для выполнения административных функций.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('mysql.hostinger.ru', 'user', 'password', 'db');

$statement = $db->prepare(<<<END
INSERT INTO REQUESTED
(
  `КОД ТОРГОВОЙ ТОЧКИ`,
  `ИМЯ ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО ЛИЦА`,
  `ДАТА ПОДАЧИ ЗАЯВКИ`,
  `ПРОДУКТ(ЛИНЕЙНОЕ ИЛИ ИНТЕРАКТИВНОЕ ТВ)`,
  `ТАРИФ`,
  `Ф.И.О`,
  `ТЕЛЕФОН`,
  `АДРЕС`
)
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? );
END
);

$statement->bind_param(
    'sssssss',
    $_POST['kod_point'],
    $_POST['urname'],
    $_POST['date'],
    $_POST['product'],
    $_POST['tarif'],
    $_POST['adname'],
    $_POST['telephone'],
    $_POST['adress']
);

$statement->execute();

echo 'Добавлено в базу данных.';
```

Comment: Надо хотя бы предупреждать об SQL инъекциях, когда советуете вставлять переменные в запрос "_как есть_".

Comment: там не только это, там еще `$PoleN` пустые, т.к. данные из поста не получаются + куча других проблем, о чем я в первом комменте написал (+ коммент @Visman о `db`)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, вообще-то я ещё пишу ответ - про это будет тоже. И да, такой запрос у автора в вопросе - я лишь указал на эту ошибку пока.

Comment: Ответ лучше сразу полный выводить, а то заминусуют за ошибки.

Comment: @Visman, как будто плюсы/минусы - это главное ))

Comment: Я к тому, что заминусованный ответ кто будет воспринимать серьезно?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev  спасибо за советы - все заработало. Буду учиться дальше